# Uncaught TypeError: timer.getTime is not a function at update

Tags: javascript

Why does my class declaration give the error "`Uncaught TypeError: timer.getTime is not a function` at update"? My other class functions, like "`timer.getStop()`", does not. Why is that?

```js
class Timer {
  constructor() {
    this.time = 0;
    this.stop = false;
    setInterval(update, 1000);
  }
  setStop(bool) {
    this.stop = bool;
  }
  setTime(t) {
    this.time = t;
  }
  getStop() {
    return this.stop;
  }
  getTime() {
    return this.time;
  }
}

function update() {
  if (timer.getTime() != 60 && !timer.getStop()) {
    timer.setTime(timer.getTime += 1)
    if (timer.getTime() <= 60) {
      clock.innerHTML = 60 - timer.getTime();
    }

    //Update Stats
    grossWPM = (entries / 5) / (time / 60);
    netWPM = grossWPM - (wrong / (time / 60));

    gross.innerHTML = 'Gross WPM: ' + grossWPM.toFixed(0);
    net.innerHTML = 'Net WPM: ' + netWPM.toFixed(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: "const timer = new Timer();" bellow my class declaration.

Comment: Don't post relevant stuff in a comment. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28536071) your question and add it there.

Comment: it is a very bad architecture: a class which calls a function of which one calls an instance of the same class. in my opinion it will never work

Comment: `timer.getTime += 1` breaks things. You overwrite your `getTime` function.

Comment: changing "timer.getTime += 1" to "timer.getTime + 1" seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Voting to close as caused by a typo. `timer.getTime += 1` should be `timer.getTime() + 1`. @fabbe680 `timer.getTime + 1` still makes no sense. `timer.getTime` is a function, not a number.

Comment: I hope that you are aware that the value of 1000ms is only an indication for the timer, and it never gives the precision of 1s, your timer will necessarily shift very quickly from the past 20 seconds, probably less ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix this

```
timer.setTime(timer.getTime += 1)
```

like that

```
timer.setTime(timer.getTime() + 1)
```